# How to detect file changes in new folder with SharpSVN?

Tags: sharpsvn

My directory structure is like that

- RootDir (under version control)
- -- NewDir (not yet under version control)
- ---- NewFile.txt (not yet under version control)

When I try to get the local modifications with SharpSVN only "NewDir" is detected, "NewFile.txt" is missing

This is my implementation

```
private Collection<SvnStatusEventArgs> GetStatuses(string rootDirPath)
{
    SvnStatusArgs sa = new SvnStatusArgs();
    sa.Depth = SvnDepth.Infinity;
    sa.RetrieveAllEntries = true;

    Collection<SvnStatusEventArgs> statuses;
    _client.GetStatus(rootDirPath, sa, out statuses);

    return statuses;
}
```

Did I miss something? I'm using SharpSVN 1.7022.3882.153

Comment: As the SVN command `svn status --diff infinity` would have shown as well. So why do you expect a difference?

Comment: Up to now I only used SVN with Clients like TortoiseSVN, not from command line. I expected to have the same behavior with SharpSVN like with Clients that also list the content of new directories